# How to use the MultiTermVectors function in elasticsearch nest

Tags: c#, elasticsearch

I have indexed a number of xml files in elasticsearch to index news and type reuters. I can then use

```
var termvecResponse = Client.TermVectors<reuters>(t => t.Index("news").Id(1).TermStatistics().Fields(f => f.Body));
```

to get the term vector for the first document. My question is how can i use the call

```
Client.MultiTermVectors<reuters>
```

I have tried

```
var idRange = Enumerable.Range(1, 10);
        
        var tvecR = Client.MultiTermVectors(new MultiTermVectorsRequest(typeof(reuters))
        {
            Documents = idRange.Select(n => new MultiTermVectorOperation<reuters>(n)
            {
                Type=typeof(reuters),
                FieldStatistics = false,
                Payloads = false,
                TermStatistics = true,
                Positions = false,
                Offsets = false
            })
        });
```

It returns empty term vectors, and the response object says the POST call was on /news/_mtermvectors instead of /news/reuters/_mtermvectors any ideas? Thanks for the help.

Low-level solution:
Used the lowlevel call like below if anyone needs it

```
string sbRequestBody = "{\"ids\":[\"1\", \"2\"],\"parameters\":{\"fields\": [\"body\"],\"term_statistics\":true}}";         
var termvecResponse =Client.LowLevel.Mtermvectors<MultiTermVectorsResponse>("news", "reuters", sbRequestBody);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documents that you're supplying to the `Documents` property on the multi term vectors request do not contain a field to target for term statistics as the single call does. If all documents will be targeting the same fields, you can use

```
var tvecR = client.MultiTermVectors(new MultiTermVectorsRequest("news", typeof(reuters))
{
    Fields = Infer.Fields<reuters>(f => f.Body), // all docs will use these fields
    Documents = idRange.Select(n => new MultiTermVectorOperation<reuters>(n)
    {
        TermStatistics = true
    })
});
```

The request here will be against `/news/reuters/_mtermvectors?fields=summary`

Answer (score 0):

Low-level solution: Used the lowlevel call like below if anyone needs it

```
string sbRequestBody = "{\"ids\":[\"1\", \"2\"],\"parameters\":{\"fields\": [\"body\"],\"term_statistics\":true}}";         
var termvecResponse =Client.LowLevel.Mtermvectors<MultiTermVectorsResponse>("news", "reuters", sbRequestBody);
```